# Passive form of A desires B to V

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the following sentence:

> John desires the audience to agree with the value-judgments in his statements.

I wanted to be able to change it to a passive form:

> These statements convey value-judgments which the audience is desired to agree with.

That's quite close to what I was trying to say, but I don't think that's proper English.

Another attempt I had was to write `audience is expected to agree with`. This kind of implies that someone wants the audience to agree with these statements, but someone can expect an audience to agree with statements without wanting them to agree to statements. I suppose that I could restructure the sentence, but I'd much rather a word or phrase that didn't require this.

Comment: Say what?  I think we're gonna need some more context and a simple explanation (in plain English) of what you want to say.

Comment: How about: *These statements convey **universal** value-judgments.*

Comment: Your original statement doesn't say the audience desires to agree with them- it says that someone (perhaps the author, perhaps the speaker) wants the audience to agree with them.  Their purpose in making the statements is to convince the audience to agree with them.  "These statements convey value-judgments with which the audience is [expected/desired] to agree."  Is this what you wanted to say?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? You are leaving out the person who has the desire or expection. The passive construction is terribly vague.

Comment: What you are really asking is:  Given the sentence, "*John desires the audience to agree with his statements*"  how do I turn it into the passive? I think your first attempt succeeds well enough. However your statement,  "*it isn't the audience who desires to agree with these statements*" is a complete non sequitur. What does that have to do with anything? Neither your sentence nor anything you said previously suggests that interpretation.

Comment: @TimRomano That's the point. The passive construction (if it is even properly English) doesn't convey that it is the person who wrote the sentence who desires the audience to agree

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Thanks, that's how to say what I want to do. I want to convert a sentence to the passive form.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use the passive voice in the first place.  In general, you're supposed to use an active voice when you can.  And then you should especially try to simplify things when you're discussing convoluted subject matter.  So I'd reconsider your entire premise.  I'd also use "wants" instead of "desires."  Just say, "So-and-so wants the audience to . . . ."

Comment: Passivisation doesn't work hereat all well; it is clumsy at best. 'It is felt desirable that the audience agree(s) with the value-judgments in [the] statements.' is grammatical and a true near-paraphrase. As Tim implies, the original is much better.

Comment: @Casebash: In your desire to convey the idea that it is not the *author* who desires  or expects the audience to agree with certain value judgments implicit in "these statements" you go too far by not identifying the party who does want their assent to them. So, try stating your core idea first in the active and then see which of those nouns (audience, statements, value judgments, desire, agreement) should really be the passive subject when you transpose the statement to the passive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a garden-path sentence. When you say

> which the audience is desired

and you add *"to agree with"*, it sounds wrong, because you start out thinking that the audience is the direct object of desire, and not that the audience's agreement is the object of desire. So you have to switch your thinking around when you read the words *"to agree with"*.

There are several ways to fix it. The minimal change is:

> These statements convey value-judgments with which the audience is desired to agree.

When you put *with* before *which*, the alternative interpretation is no longer possible.

Comment: "Desired" is a participial adjective with only a passive meaning, and can't take the "audience" as it's direct object. So no matter where you put "with", the sentence would mean the same. But I agree that your version is clearer.

Comment: Now that you mention that, another similar construction is, `These statements convey value-judgments with which it is hoped the audience will agree`.

Answer (score 0):

> Past participles used as adjectives normally have a passive meaning. A ***broken*** chair is a chair that ***has been broken***. But there are some exceptions - for example, an ***escaped*** prisoner is a prisoner who ***has escaped***. Other exceptions:
>   a retired teacher, a fallen leaf, a vanished civilisation, a collapsed building, developed countries, advanced students, a grown-up son, faded colours, increased activity, swollen ankles, ...

Swan, Michael. *Oxford English Grammar Course*.

As you see, all the examples above (of past-participial adjectives with active meaning) are from *intransitive* verbs. I doubt that there are any transitive verbs whose past-participial adjectives could have an active meaning.

*To desire* is a transitive verb, so this clause:

> ... the audience is desired to agree with.

has nothing to do with what the audience desires, it's about what is desired *of* the audience. If you need further proof, here:

[**desired**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/desired?a=british) (adjective):
that is ​wanted: *His words had the desired ​effect*.

**Edit**: In short: "*judgments which the audience **is desired** to agree with*" is alright, because it has only a passive meaning and is not ambiguous.

Comment: So essentially you're saying passivisation doesn't work here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, quite the contrary. In the earliest version of the question, the OP was unsure if _judgments which the audience **is desired** to agree with_ meant _judgments which the audience **desires** to agree with_. I answered that this participial adjective is clear and has only a passive meaning, so it's alright to be used here. Then I realized the question had been edited and I was too lazy to modify my answer.

Comment: In that case, I'll have to point out that "are desired to agree with" and "is desired to agree with" show about 7 and 6 Google hits respectively. this contrasts with 7.4 million and 13.6 million for "are required to agree with" and "is required to agree with". The verb construction 'desire X to' does not transitivise with high idiomaticity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you drop the "agree with" part, and search for "is/are desired to", you'll find that this construction is not that rare.

Comment: The snag is that the pretty common ''is desired [in order] to" / (& the related "for the purpose of V-ing" sense) false positive then kicks in. The use of "It is desired to V" (very light subject)  also occurs and _is_ acceptable. But even "John is desired to" is extremely rare on the web. Most of the early examples I found on Google which are _not_ false positives sadly seem grammatically challenged. The comparison of 6 with 7 million holds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Still I wouldn't go so far as to call it a _wrong_ construction. Nothing is grammatically wrong with it, and it's not altogether abandoned by authors. You can find so many legitimate examples of this usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+desired+to%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&tbas=0&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0CBQQpwVqFQoTCNfvn6Kd_MgCFYXJFAodYY8CaQ&biw=1600&bih=799&dpr=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.106923889,d.d24&ech=1&psi=x9Y8VpfwJ4WTU-GeisgG.1446827738100.3&ei=x9Y8VpfwJ4WTU-GeisgG&emsg=NCSR&noj=1).

Comment: The first ten or so of which date from 1755, 1762, 1669, 1669, 1774, 1669, 1669 .... It seems less used nowadays than _Yea, verily_.  It's not standard usage nowadays. Of course, OP's 'proper English' is nebulous. But we shouldn't be recommending things that will make OP sound unidiomatic or probably even weird.

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't want to restructure the sentence, but this isn't a very large restructure. The "desired to agree with" sounds okay to me as a native speaker, but I cannot confirm whether or not it's standard English.

The original sentence is as follows.

> John desires the audience to agree with the value-judgments in his statements.

To reword it to the passive form, we must first find what John desires.

> the audience to agree with the value-judgements in his statements

The awkwardness I believe comes from the infinitive constructure of "the audience to agree" being separated, so let's reword it to leave out the infinitive but mean the same thing.

> the audience's agreement with the value-judgements in his statement.

This is what is desired, and lacking the infinitive construction, it should sound less awkward when transformed the passive form. The basic passive form would be:

> The audience's agreement is desired.

Using the same structure as you example sentence, we can change the original sentence to:

> These statements convey value-judgments for which the audience's agreement is desired.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I just wanted to retain the passive voice, but I didn't know how to say what I wanted.

Comment: Your suggestion is ungrammatical.

Comment: I am stupefied by the statement "sounds okay to my ear, but I have no idea whether it's proper English". If you aren't a native speaker, then please clearly state just that. If you are, the statement frankly makes little sense, if any. Also, could you please define "proper English"? That is not a term I am familiar with. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The preposition in your final sentence is wrong. Un-passivizing the final sentence, we get *"the audience's agreement is desired **of** the value-judgements conveyed by these statements."* The preposition is wrong. I cannot say *"I desire your agreement **of** this value-judgment"*. It has to be *to* or *with* or *for*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I am a native English speaker, and by proper English I just meant standard English. While yes, as a native speaker I should know how to use the language, there are often times where what sounds correct to a native speaker may be wrong because we don't all go around speaking completely standard English. I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you, I didn't notice. I've edited my answer to use "for".

Answer (score -1):

I would put it like this:

**These statements convey value-judgments with which the audience is supposed to agree.**

Or,

**These statements convey value-judgments of which the audience is supposed to agree.**

Or, since there is some debate concerning the use of value-judgements:

**These statements convey subjective evaluations with/of which the audience is supposed to agree.**

Comment: 'Be supposed to' carries a sense of moral obligation (I am supposed to help with the dishes) which is not the same as 'be a desired outcome'.

Comment: ***of** which*???? Un-passivize this: *"I would like you to agree of this fact"*. That's wrong. You should use ***to*** or ***with***.

Comment: For what it's worth, I upvoted this answer because it is close despite this connotation